# Корень 0-вой степени

Tags: математика

Ребят, знаю что вопрос вообще не по теме программирования, но... Писал программу, там был метод написанный мной, который вычисляет корень n-й степени, а в процессе теста, у меня появился вопрос: Любое число в нулевой степени равно единице, а чему тогда равен корень нулевой степени из единицы?

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Does the zeroth root exist?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/962807/1665)

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что он не относится к теме сайта.

Answer (score 3):

Вы никогда не сталкивались с 0<sup>0</sup>? Если рассматривать как x<sup>0</sup> - то это должно быть 1, если как 0<sup>x</sup> - то нулем... Я к тому, что корень нулевой степени можно рассматривать в лучшем случае только как предел при показателе корня, стремящемся к нулю - только в этом случае все еще хуже - конечный предел в данном случае не существует.

Словом, его просто нет.

Ну, разве что кроме как для x=1 :)

Answer (score 2):

Я не математик, но рискну предположить, что само понятие корня 0-ой степени не имеет смысла. Как известно, корень n-й степени из числа x - это такое число y, которое, будучи возведено в n-ую степень, даст x. То есть y^n = x.
При этом известно, что число, возведённое в нулевую степень - это единица. Следовательно, если x отличается от единицы, то нет такого числа, которое, будучи возведённым в нулевую степень, дало бы этот самый x.
Вероятно, матанализ имеет какой-то ответ на этот вопрос, но это уже другая история

Comment: Если рассматривать как предел `x^(1/y)` при `y -> 0`, то получаем при `x > 1` бесконечность, при `x = 1` единицу и при `0 < x < 1` ноль.

Answer (score 0):

Когда корень представляют в виде степени, то получают дробные значения квадратный корень равносилен степени 1/2, кубический - 1/3 и т.д. В итоге получается бессмысленное с точки зрения математики выражение степени "нулевого" корня 1/0 . Деление на нуль в результате которого мы получим бесконечность а значит и корень нулевого степеня равен перевернутой восмерке :)

Answer (score 0):

Где -то выше был комент, что √a =a^(1 / n), где n - степень корня, я только в 8 классе, но по-моему в матанализе есть такая вещь как неопределенность это теория пределов вроде бы, и там на 0 делить можно)

Comment: Если с точки зрения пределов, то зависит от того, какое число под корнем. К примеру, для единицы: lim(x->0) 1^(1/x) = 1, для других значений рассматриваются приближения к нулю слева или справа

Comment: Нигде нельзя *делить* на ноль. Другое дело, что можно вычислить предел выражения, например, `1/x^2` при `x -> 0`, но это уже совсем другое. И, вообще говоря, запись `1/0` не является некорректной, но непосредственно делить на ноль нельзя.

Comment: Это теория пределов, так? Мне стоит изучить или хотябы отчасти вникнуть в неё что бы понять это?

Comment: Скорее всего сейчас скажу бред, но лучше раз опозорится и понять чем не знать) Допустим у меня есть некое число x, при умножение его на 1 оноже и останется, тогда, что мне мешает сделать что-то такое: x = x * (0 / 0) поидее раз яислитель и знаминатель, я про нули, равны, то эта дробь равна 1? И если да то по сути неважно какой x, ведь x * 0 / 0 = 0 / 0. Разве не так? И это равно 1!??

Comment: @Funny Lamer Старайтесь писать ответ содержательно.

Comment: @Владимир что вы имеете ввиду?